# Android app force closing when opening amarino connection

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development, and have run into a problem I seem unable to solve.
My android app should be able to communicate with my arduino device, sending info
to and retrieving info from my device. I have set up my connection between the two
with a bluetooth device and I am using amarino to facilitate the communication.

Now I can connect with amarino and send data and receive data, now I want to do this from
my app. The problem comes when I enter this line:

```
private static final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "07:12:04:16:68:18"; 
Amarino.connect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);
```

The number is the MAC address of my bluetooth adapter connected to my arduino device.
As soon as I run my app on my phone it just force closes due to unexpected error.
Now as I said, I am a bit of a noob when it comes to android, so I installed logCat to try get some log info out of it. All I got from it was this somewhat unhelpful error message:

> com.example.projectgreetv3/.StartingPlace
>    10-24 15:22:55.140 E/AndroidRuntime(4906): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectgreetv3/com.example.projectgreetv3.StartingPlace}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectgreetv3.StartingPlace in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.projectgreetv3-1.apk]
>   10-24 15:22:55.140 E/AndroidRuntime(4906): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectgreetv3.StartingPlace in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.projectgreetv3-1.apk]
>   10-24 15:22:55.148 W/ActivityManager(539):   Force finishing activity com.example.projectgreetv3/.StartingPlace
>   10-24 15:21:51.726 I/UinboxLogger(4585): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >>   intent.getData() : com.example.projectgreetv3
>   10-24 15:21:52.382 I/UninstallAppProgress(4575): Finished uninstalling pkg: com.example.projectgreetv3
>   10-24 15:22:52.523 D/PackageManager(539): Scanning package com.example.projectgreetv3

I hope someone can help me with this, as I am on wits end.

For more info on: 
 - Arduino:
 - http://www.arduino.cc/
- Amarino:
http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/

Comment: First of all - you should not perform any communication in `onCreate()` which is executed on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you look a bit further down on your stacktrace (in the logcat) you will probably see that the cause of this crash is an  NetworkOnMainThreadException. (If you are running Android 3.0 or higher)

Please make sure that you do all your network communication on a separate thread (Thread/ASyncTask).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html